# Is there a way to use the html written by js in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added 5 buttons in js to html and I want them to be defined with a one second delay, and because of this js, when it reaches the addEventListener line, those buttons are not defined and gives an error.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="btn-adder"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
}
body{
    background: rgb(61, 61, 61);
}
#btn-adder{
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#btn-adder button{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const btnAdder = document.getElementById("btn-adder");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        btnAdder.innerHTML += `<button id="btn${i}">Button ${i}</button>`;
    }, 1000);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById(`btn${i}`).addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(`Button ${i} clicked`);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to make the addEventListener recognize the new variables?

Comment: Attach the event handlers when the buttons are inserted into the DOM (inside of your `setTimeout` function), or use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) (attach a single handler to your `btnAdder` and use the `event.target` to determine which button was clicked)

Comment: It's the setTimeout which the issue.  "setTimeout  is an asynchronous function, meaning that the timer function will not pause execution of other functions in the functions stack." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#working_with_asynchronous_functions  
 You can use @billyonecan advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the issue where the addEventListener encounters undefined variables due to the delayed creation of buttons, can modify code to ensure that the buttons are created before attempting to add event listeners.

One way to achieve this is by wrapping the button creation and event listener attachment in a function and calling that function after all the buttons have been added. Here's an updated version of code:

```
const btnAdder = document.getElementById("btn-adder");

// Function to create buttons
function createButtons() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        btnAdder.innerHTML += `<button id="btn${i}">Button ${i}</button>`;
    }

    // Add event listeners after buttons are created
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.getElementById(`btn${i}`).addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(`Button ${i} clicked`);
        });
    }
}

// Call the function after a delay
setTimeout(createButtons, 1000);
```

In this modification, the createButtons function is responsible for both creating buttons and adding event listeners. By calling this function after a one-second delay, you ensure that the buttons are defined when the event listeners are attached, resolving the issue of undefined variables during the event listener registration.

Comment: This answer looks like it was copy-pasted from ChatGPT

Answer (score 4):

An approach close to what billyonecan mentioned but with use of appendChild instead of innerHTML which can lead to unwanted behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        body{
            background: rgb(61, 61, 61);
        }
        #btn-adder{
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #btn-adder button{
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="btn-adder"></div>
        <script>
        const btnAdder = document.getElementById("btn-adder");
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                let b = document.createElement('button');
                b.id = "btn" + i;
                b.textContent = "Button " + i;
                btnAdder.appendChild(b);
                
                document.getElementById("btn"+i).addEventListener("click", function () {
                console.log(`Button ${i} clicked`);
            });
         },1000 );

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible and you don't even need the second loop, which is slowing down your code. (even though you probably won't notice it)

Instead of adding the HTML directly to the `btn-adder`, you can create a new button and directly attach the eventlistener to it.

You can create a new HTML element with [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and then add all attributes, eventlisteners and everything else you need to the button.
Finally you'll add the newly created button with [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) as a new child element to your `btn-adder` element.

```js
const btnAdder = document.getElementById("btn-adder");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // create button
        const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
        buttonElement.id = `btn${i}`;
        buttonElement.textContent = `Button ${i}`
        
        // add eventlistener to the created button
        buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(`Button ${i} clicked`);
        });
        
        // add button to their parent
        btnAdder.appendChild(buttonElement);
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
}
body{
    background: rgb(61, 61, 61);
}
#btn-adder{
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#btn-adder button{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="btn-adder"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```